# Visual Studio 2017 TS2304 and TS2583 errors in Angular project but ng build works fine

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

Have a .NET Core 2.2 project started with the Angular template.  Replaced the /ClientApp folder with a new CLI-generated angular 7 app.  Both VS Build & ng build without issue.  However, on the VS error list tab there are about 16 TS-related errors, 3 of which are

```
Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Iterable'.
Error   TS2583  (TS) Cannot find name 'Map'.
Error   TS1219  (TS) Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.
```

This is driving me nuts.  Anyone stumble onto this and have a fix?

my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

**[ update ]**
Just to add details - I noticed that the errors were all referencing the same file, which was a file I recently added via VS > add new item > typescript file.  Turns out this adds the file references in the csproj file like so:

```
<!--<ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ClientApp\src\app\mycomponent\mysvc.service.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>-->
  <!--<ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\app\mycomponent\audit.service.ts" />
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="ClientApp\src\app\shared\models\commodel-result.model.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after finally managing to resolve this issue but still not really understanding why the types started causing trouble, here is what I did.  See the update in the post above.  I commented out the file references in the csproj file and the the "fake" TS errors went away.

Note to self and others - its probably best to add new angular component/service files via the angular cli to avoid this.